# Filter content by taxonomy url

Tags: views

I have a view page that displays a group of content fields. Attached to the content type there is a taxonomy term field.

How do I get contextual filters to recognize second path component of the URL and then filter it against the taxonomy terms on the page views? See attached images

[image: Contextual filter]

[image: view page]

Comment: Where does the second path component of the URL come from? (Path auto, manual URL alias, menu tree, term, parent term?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this approach:

First create a views and add a path with wildcard
[image]

Second add a contextual filter Content: Has taxonomy term ID and do this:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Third test it, type the path name of your taxonomy and hit update preview.
[image]

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks, this really helps me understand contextual filters in views

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a relationship to your taxonomy, and on your view path you can specify which field you want to use to filter. You also have to add a contextual filter to your view.